How can I know if an AWS ECS service is idle?
Is there an easy way to know if an ECS service is idle? We have a good number of legacy ECS services running in AWS that use almost 0 cpu/memory.

ECS tasks are just docker containers. The ECS service itself does not have any real insight into what is running inside those containers, other than to report the amount of memory and CPU they are using.
If the ECS services are hosting web apps fronted by an AWS load balancer, then you could look at the load balancer's metrics to see if any requests are being sent to the services at all.
Otherwise, you will need to look at the logs of the ECS tasks to see if they are doing anything.
